# How to disable (and also enable when necessary) the autocomplete feature of textbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Suppose I have an autocomplete control for search purpose in my wp7 app, and I have a listbox(populated). When I select an item from the listbox, it is copied to the textbox(autocomplete) but it displays the autocomplete options. In this case, I do not want to display the autocomplete options (only for this instance). How can I disable the autcomplete feature when pasting something into the autocomplete control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a direct option to disable it, but you could set the `MinimumPrefixLength` to `-1`. This will prevent the auto-complete part from running.